# Конструктор с параметрами не копирует массив символов в поле (переменную) класса

Tags: c++, строки, классы, visual-c++

Проблемы пока две:

1. Ошибка при определении переменной "Не существует подходящего конструктора для преобразования из
   **"const char[15]"** в **"String"**. Компилятор ругается на конструктор с параметром, даже если заменить функцию **strcpy** на цикл **for**, ничего не меняется. Пример из книги Р. Лафоре.
2. Не работает функция **strcpy**. Но если добавить строку *#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS* то компилятор вроде проглатывает. Насколько я понял такие функции считаются небезопасными и компилятор на них ругается. А эта строка заставляет компилятор это игнорировать. Можно ли обойтись без этой строки?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
////////////////////////////////////
class String
{
    private:
        enum { SZ = 80 };
        char str[SZ];
    public:
        String()
        {
            strcpy(str, "");
        }
        String(char s[])
        {
            strcpy(str, s);
        }
        void display()
        {
            cout << str;
        }
        String operator+(String ss) const
        {
            String temp;
            if (strlen(str) + strlen(ss.str) < SZ)
            {
                strcpy(temp.str, str);
                strcat(temp.str, ss.str);
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Переполнение!!!" << endl;
                exit(1);
            }
            return temp;
        }
};
////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    String s1 = "С Рождеством! ";
    String s2 = "С Новым годом!";
    String s3;

    s1.display();
    s2.display();
    s3.display();

    s3 = s1 + s2;

    s1.display();
    s3.display();
    cout << endl << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
String(const char s[])
```

По второму вопросу - можно отключить это предупреждение

```
#pragma warning( disable : 4996 )
```

но с

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

все же корректнее (или использовать безопасные функции).

Comment: `strcpy_s` вместо `strcpy`

Comment: На какие функции можно заменить? Если использовать цикл for и strlen это решает проблему. Вобщем спасибо помогло. Как я понял по поводу первого вопроса это просто особенность синтаксиса?

Comment: Это не особенность, а строгая типизация. Вы по сути объявили в `String(char s[])` - здесь я **буду менять** содержимое `s`. Неважно, что на самом деле не меняете - вы затребовали такую возможность! Но менять содержимое строкового литерала нельзя - вот компилятор и возмутился..